# Why does Jenkins fail to build due to it Sass files not able to be downloaded in angular4 project?

Tags: angular, jenkins, angular-cli

I am trying to build an angular4 project with angular cli and Jenkins. The project builds fine locally on my MacBook Pro, but when running the build script in Jenkins it fails and throws the following error. It seems like the problem is being caused by a Jenkins setting or something, and Jenkins should be able to build the project if it builds fine on my local computer. This is the error message. How can this be solved? The error message is quite long, so I am only including the part that I believe to be the most relevant. Thanks!

```
> node-sass@4.5.3 install /ci/work/jenkins/workspace/vardgivare-frontend/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.3/linux-x64-48_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.3/linux-x64-48_binding.node": 

ETIMEDOUT

Timed out attemping to establish a remote connection

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g. 

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall /ci/work/jenkins/workspace/vardgivare-frontend/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js
```

Comment: is it behind proxy ?

Comment: yes I believe it is

Answer (score 1):

You need to Set proxies

For GitHub the commands are

```
git config --global http.proxy whatever-url

git config --global https.proxy whaterver-url
```

You will even need to do those at node Level, as when it tries to do npm install it will need those.

The commands are

```
npm config set proxy whatever-url

npm config set https-proxy whatever-url
```